# Reuse playground code in a regular Xcode project

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I'm having some code to create a UICollectionView on my playground. The code works and previews just fine. Now I'm trying to reuse it into a Xcode Project, I'm not getting any errors but the build on the simulator is just plain white.. Nothing to see at all

Can someone explain the reason of this? :)

```
import UIKit
//import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    var myCollectionView:UICollectionView?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 60, height: 60)
        
        myCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)

        myCollectionView?.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
        myCollectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        
        myCollectionView?.dataSource = self
        myCollectionView?.delegate = self
 
        view.addSubview(myCollectionView ?? UICollectionView())
        
        self.view = view
    }
}

extension MyViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 9 // How many cells to display
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let myCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath)
        myCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        return myCell
    }
}

extension MyViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
 
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       print("User tapped on item \(indexPath.row)")
    }
}

// Present the view controller in the Live View window
//PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

Comment: Did you expect `PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()` to work in an iOS app? If you are using storyboards, you should set `MyViewController` as the class of a VC in the storyboard.

Comment: No, I did not expect de 'PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()' to work in an iOS app. That's why I put // to disable it... I also deleted the last line of code but still no effect. So, how do I set MyViewController as the class of a VC in my storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you go to the storyboard, select the view controller in the document outline, and change the class name from UIViewController to MyViewController in the Identity Inspector?  If you don't make that change, Xcode assumes you want to use the default UIViewController, which is blank.